# $(A,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set. That each finite non-empty subset of $A$ has a $maxB$ implies $(A,\leq)$ is totally ordered.

Tags: relations, order-theory

My textbook contains the following exercise:

> Let $(A,\leq)$ be a partially ordered set.  Prove that if each finite non-empty subset of $A$ has a greatest element, then $(A,\leq)$ is totally ordered.

I'm struggling to prove this.
I began by just considering some subset of $A$ containing two elements.  I denote this subset of $A$ as $B_1$: $B_1 \subseteq A$.  I denote the two elements in $B_1$ as $x_1$ and $x_2$: $B_1$={$x_1, x_2$}.  Assuming the antecedent of the above conditional sentence, it's true that $x_1$ or $x_2$ is the $maxB_1$.  Then $x_2 \ge x_1$ or $x_1 \ge x_2$.  Now, suppose $x_1=x_2$.  Then, it's clear that $B_1$ is totally ordered.  Then, it remains to show that in the cases $x_1 \lt x_2$ and $x_2 \lt x_1$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $\le$-comparable.  (Establishing this fact essentially establishes the rest of the proof, well, at least to my thinking.)  It is at this point that I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Turn your argument around. Suppose that $A$ is *not* totally ordered. Then there are $x_1,x_2\in A$ such that $x_1\not\le x_2$ and $x_2\not\le x_1$. What can you say about the set $\{x_1,x_2\}$?

Comment: Wow . . .I feel very much like an imbecile.  I still don't see it.

Comment: @Jordan: Does that two-element set have a greatest element?

Comment: My answer is yes, but I'm thinking that that's wrong.  I'm thinking that if $x_1\not\le x_2$ and $x_2\not\le x_1$, then it must be the case that $x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$, which implies that there is a greatest element.  But as I said, I'm thinking that I'm wrong, since proof by contradiction is being utilized, yet I still don't see it.  Thus, I'm guessing my understanding of comparability is off.

Comment: @Jordan: If $x_1$ were the largest element of the set, then by definition we’d have $x_2\le x_1$, which is not the case. Similarly, if $x_2$ were the largest element, we’d have $x_1\le x_2$, which is not the case, Thus, neither $x_1$ nor $x_2$ can be the largest element of the set, and since they’re its *only* elements, it has no largest element. Does that help?

Comment: I'm thinking that I've been confused about the notation; so, if a text states: *the ordered pair $(A,\le)$ is a partially ordered set*, then the relation on A that's under consideration is $\le$.  The *second coordinate* so-to-speak refers to a relation on the set specified in the *first coordinate*.  Is that right?  I interpreted from my textbook that the notation $\le$ refers to *some* general relation.

Comment: @Jordan: Yes, $\le$ refers to the specific partial order on the set $A$ mentioned in the notation $\langle A,\le\rangle$ presenting $A$ as a partially ordered set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27106/discussion-between-jordan-miller-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @Jordan: Okay, I’m there (though I’ll have to leave very soon for a dental appointment).

Comment: just to check my understanding.   $\le$ refers to the relation of $\le$, and it doesn't refer to *some* general partial order relation?

Comment: @Jordan: That’s correct. Perhaps it would have been clearer had the partial order been defined as $\langle A,\preceq\rangle$, and the symbol $\preceq$ then been used throughout; you’d have been less inclined to suppose that it referred to some previously known order relation.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between a partial order and a total order is that in a total order any two elements can be compared. But if every set of two elements has a maximum, by definition of maximum it means those two elements can be compared.